# How can I insert my ajax response values to a specific div element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call, which retrieves data and should insert it into the desired div box. However, I can only use one parameter in the success method to fetch the data, not multiple parameters.
One super bad/cheap fix would've been multiple ajax calls, but I just know there has to be an easier and less dirty solution than creating different calls/scripts to fetch my data that way. I also tried, as mentioned above, with multiple parameters, in the hope that maybe that would've worked.

my ajax call looks like this:

```
function retrieveQuestion() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'getSpecificPost.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
}
```

my php script looks like this (not all of it, considering the script works, and my main problem is just how to append certain data to certain divs):

```
    $sqli = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title = ?';
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqli)) {
        echo 'Error no stmt prepared';
        exit();
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $title);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row['title'];
                echo $row['name'];
                echo $row['id'];
            }
        }
```

so let's say, I have 3 div boxes, which are already made, so they don't get created dynamically.

I would like to append $row['title'] to the div box with an id title, the $row['name'] to a div box with id name, and the one with $row['id'] to a div box with the id, id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSON**

JSON is a human readable text format generally used for transportation of data between server and client.

The **json_enocde()** function in PHP converts the array into a json string and **JSON.parse()** function in javascript converts the json string into an array of objects with the appropriate values populated in it.

The Javascript equivalent of json_encode() is **JSON.stringify()** and PHP equivalent of JSON.parse() is **json_decode()**.

**PHP**

```
$sqli = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title = ?';
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqli)) {
    echo 'Error no stmt prepared';
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $title);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {

        $json_response = [];

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $json_response[] = $row;
        }

        //Echo data as JSON
        echo json_encode($json_response);
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
    function retrieveQuestion() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'getSpecificPost.php',
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(response) {

               response = JSON.parse(response);

               $("#title").text(response[0].title);
               $("#name").text(response[0].name);
               $("#id").text(response[0].id);
           }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what your code did? it not only helps me, but I think it will help other people aswell

Comment: I recommend using OOP syntax with mysqli -- it's more concise.  I would also recommend using `exit(json_encode(fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)));` instead of all of that other server-side bloat.  `$_POST` is not recommended when the action is "fetch/read" from the server-side. This answer is rather undercooked because it is not attempting to iterate the multidimensional response data.

Comment: Ah, okay, benefit of the doubt -- the OP's code seems to suggest that there is only one row of data expected.  If this is true, then the response data structure should be one-dimensional (flat).

Answer (score 0):

Since Ajax response all data together. You have two choices to do...
1. Construct your html divs in server php page and directly insert in desired div where you want to update.
2. You have to go through complex JavaScript and json data... Receive data in json format and later on place in manually in desired place.
But I suggest the first option create your div with respective ids in server and on success event directly insert it in div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning a JSON with all the data? 
Something like this:

```
echo '{ title:', $row['title'], ', name: ', $row['name'], ', id: ', $row['id'], ' }'
```

You can also create an object and use `json_encode` if you do not want to bother building the JSON yourself.

Then in your JavaScript you can change your success function to this:

```
success: function(response) {
    response = JSON.parse(response); // converts string to Object
    for(var property in response) { // loops for title, name and id
        // Sets the text of the element with id: "title", "name" or "id"
        document.querySelector("#" + property).textContent = result[property];
    }
}
```

The code in JavaScript parses the JSON from a string to an Ob

Answer (score 0):

try to send it as one string in php and use comma's then in your ajax use this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getSpecificPost.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
         var data = response.split(",");
         $('#title').val(data[0]);
         $('#name').val(data[1]);
         $('#id').val(data[2]);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access to you DOM html when ajax succsess. Look at this example:

Edit your php  and set "return $row"

```
//...
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               return $row
            }
        }
```

```js
//here is your Succes ajas response
//success: function(response) {
 
var response=[];//this line is not necesari , i write because i dont hae response;
response['name'] ='testName';
response['title'] ='testtitle';
response['id'] ='testid';
$('#title').html(response['title']);
$('#name').html(response['name']);
$('#id').html(response['id']);
//   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="id"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to dynamically update your static page with the response you get from the server.

- Create `HTML` using Javascript and add values to it
- Since you are using jquery which is a really good `DOM` manipulation library you can have your `HTML` as it is. And update your DOM when you received your response

  -- Note - I am just trying to replicate your issue and showing you possible approaches.

Try to type with any product name in input box

```js
//Suppose your response contains this form of data

let products = [
 {id : '1', product_name : 'amazon', img : 'something'},
 {id : '2', product_name : 'snapdeal', img : 'something'},
 {id : '3', product_name : 'google', img : 'something'}  
]
let input = $('#search')
input.keyup(function(){
 let showingContacts;
  if($(this).val()){
    let match = new RegExp($(this).val())
    showingProducts =  products.filter(product=> match.test(product.product_name))
    }else
     showingProducts = products
  updateDom(showingProducts)
})

const updateDom = products =>{
 $('.contents').html('')
 products.forEach(product =>{
   $('.contents').append(`<div class="card">
    <h1 id="title">${product.product_name}</h1>
  </div>`)
  })
}
updateDom(products)
```

```css
.contents {display: flex; flex-flow: wrap;}

.card {
background: wheat;
padding: 1.875rem;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search">

<div class = "contents">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return JSON from your server by creating an array containing all the rows and encode it to JSON

```
$sqli = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title = ?';
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqli)) {
   echo 'Error no stmt prepared';
   exit();
} else {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $title);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
   $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if ($resultCheck > 0) {

      $response = [];

      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $response[] = $row;
      }
      //Return the array as json
      print json_encode($response);
   } 
}
```

And then when you get the response you can loop through the response in the success method of your ajax call

```
function retrieveQuestion() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'getSpecificPost.php',
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(response) {
           $("#title").html("<ul>");
           $("#name").html("<ul>");
           $("#id").html("<ul>");
           for (var val in response) {
               if (response.hasOwnProperty(val)) { 
                   $("#title").append("<li>"+response[val].title+"</li>");
                   $("#name").append("<li>"+response[val].name+"</li>");
                   $("#id").append("<li>"+response[val].id+"</li>");
               }
           }
           $("#title").append("</ul>");
           $("#name").append("</ul>");
           $("#id").append("</ul>");
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I recommend using OOP syntax with mysqli -- it's more concise.  I would also recommend using `exit(json_encode(fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)));` instead of all of that other server-side bloat.  `$_POST` is not recommended when the action is merely to "fetch/read" data.