# How to validate dimensions and format of an image URL in PHP?

Tags: php

My system does not host images on my server, I am using the one APIfrom imgurso it is only valid that the imput field where I insert the image URL is not empty:

```
$CoverPage = $_POST["cover_page"];


if (empty($_POST['cover_page'])) {
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["cover_page" =>"Image requiere"]]);
        exit;
    }
```

But I need to validate that path of that image, which has minimum dimensions 400x400may be more but it cannot be less, image formats allowed png, jpe, svg,among others, this is in case another URLwrong path was added .

Image URL:

```
https://i.imgur.com/UkvbM34.jpg
```

> It is important that in the image validation only allow the URL to be from imgur

Javascript imgur
,,,,,

```
(function (root, factory) {
    "use strict";
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        root.Imgur = factory();
    }
}(this, function () {
    "use strict";
    var Imgur = function (options) {
        if (!this || !(this instanceof Imgur)) {
            return new Imgur(options);
        }

        if (!options) {
            options = {};
        }

        if (!options.clientid) {
            throw 'Provide a valid Client Id here: https://api.imgur.com/';
        }

        this.clientid = options.clientid;
        this.endpoint = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image';
        this.callback = options.callback || undefined;
        this.dropzone = document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone');
        this.info = document.querySelectorAll('.info');

        this.run();
    };

    Imgur.prototype = {
        createEls: function (name, props, text) {
            var el = document.createElement(name), p;
            for (p in props) {
                if (props.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    el[p] = props[p];
                }
            }
            if (text) {
                el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            }
            return el;
        },
        insertAfter: function (referenceNode, newNode) {
            referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
        },
        post: function (path, data, callback) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.open('POST', path, true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID ' + this.clientid);
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                        var response = '';
                        try {
                            response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        } catch (err) {
                            response = this.responseText;
                        }
                        callback.call(window, response);
                    } else {
                        throw new Error(this.status + " - " + this.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhttp.send(data);
            xhttp = null;
        },
        createDragZone: function () {
            var p1, p2, input;
            //Dejar archivo de imagen aquí
            //O haga clic aquí para seleccionar la imagen
            p1 = this.createEls('p', {}, 'Leave image file here');
            p2 = this.createEls('p', {}, 'Or click here to select the image');
            input = this.createEls('input', {type: 'file', className: 'input', accept: 'image/*'}); //name: 'cover_page', 

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.info, function (zone) {
                zone.appendChild(p1);
                zone.appendChild(p2);
            }.bind(this));
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.dropzone, function (zone) {
                zone.appendChild(input);
                this.status(zone);
                this.upload(zone);
            }.bind(this));
        },
        loading: function () {
            var div, table, img;

            div = this.createEls('div', {className: 'loading-modal'});
            table = this.createEls('table', {className: 'loading-table'});
            img = this.createEls('img', {className: 'loading-image', src: 'imgur/api/css/loading-spin.svg'});

            div.appendChild(table);
            table.appendChild(img);
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        },
        status: function (el) {
            var div = this.createEls('div', {className: 'status'});

            this.insertAfter(el, div);
        },
        matchFiles: function (file, zone) {
            var status = zone.nextSibling;

            if (file.type.match(/image/) && file.type !== 'image/svg+xml') {
                document.body.classList.add('loading');
                status.classList.remove('bg-success', 'bg-danger');
                status.innerHTML = '';

                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('image', file);
                fd.append('type', 'URL');

                this.post(this.endpoint, fd, function (data) {
                    document.body.classList.remove('loading');
                    typeof this.callback === 'function' && this.callback.call(this, data);
                }.bind(this));
            } else {
                status.classList.remove('bg-success');
                status.classList.add('bg-danger');
                status.innerHTML = 'Invalid archive';
            }
        },
        upload: function (zone) {
            var events = ['dragenter', 'dragleave', 'dragover', 'drop'],
                file, target, i, len;

            zone.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' && e.target.type === 'file') {
                    target = e.target.files;

                    for (i = 0, len = target.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                        file = target[i];
                        this.matchFiles(file, zone);
                    }
                }
            }.bind(this), false);

            events.map(function (event) {
                zone.addEventListener(event, function (e) {
                    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' && e.target.type === 'file') {
                        if (event === 'dragleave' || event === 'drop') {
                            e.target.parentNode.classList.remove('dropzone-dragging');
                        } else {
                            e.target.parentNode.classList.add('dropzone-dragging');
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            });
        },
        run: function () {
            var loadingModal = document.querySelector('.loading-modal');

            if (!loadingModal) {
                this.loading();
            }
            this.createDragZone();
        }
    };

    return Imgur;
}));

var feedback = function(res) {
    if (res.success === true) {
        var get_link = res.data.link.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
        document.querySelector('.status').classList.add('bg-success');
        //document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = 'Image : ';
        //document.querySelector('.loading-image').src = res.data.link;
        $('.urlimg').val(res.data.link);
    }
};

new Imgur({
    clientid: 'f048780ea2fd4cd', //You can change this ClientID
    callback: feedback
});
,,,,,
```

Comment: Do you want to validate the image after its upload?

Comment: _Side note:_ Check `empty($_POST['cover_page'])` _before_ you try and use it.

Comment: Have you tried using [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)?

Comment: @bpanatta I think it should be before, this would be from the API, but I do not want error messages as a pop-up window but a text of the error below the imput field

Comment: @Pepe, then you should do a client-side validation, probably from JS, in which case take a look at the answer by Zoli Szabó. Any other case the image must pass trough the PHP app server, that will validate the image and send it to Imgur.

Comment: Just please update this question with the javascript tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the image directly from the client-side to the imgur API, via JS, or send to your PHP app server (server-side validation), which will validate and send the image to the imgur.

I recommend you using the server-side validation. In this case the image will be uploaded to your app server and get stored in a temporary directory, where you can access it with PHP, like this:

```php
if ( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
        $size = getimagesize( $file['tmp_name'] );
    }
}
```

To get the image size with JS, just do the following before submitting the image:

```js
var img = document.getElementById( 'imageid' ); 
if ( img.clientWidth > 400 && img.clientHeight > 400 ) {
    // Send the image to imgUr
}
```

Comment: Using this example: `echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["cover_page" =>"Image requiere"]]);` I can insert an error message below the imput field coinciding with the name of the imput field <input name = "cover_page"> a message needs to be printed or else how will the editor know that it is not meeting the requirements of the picture

Comment: You can echo the JSON if you are sending the image through AJAX. In this case you will have to add the message to some element in the page. Another way of doing it is rendering the page again, echoing the message in some element of the page.

Comment: @Pepe take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437247/how-can-i-insert-my-ajax-response-values-to-a-specific-div-element

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can use PHP's native [`getimagesize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get info on an image.

Particularly speaking about imgur, they have a nice API you can use: https://apidocs.imgur.com/#2078c7e0-c2b8-4bc8-a646-6e544b087d0f